# email() is not a function via onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Can someone please help me? Am I missing something really obvious? I can't seem to call my function to run my ajax call. Much appreciate any help. Thanks

HTML:

this is just snippets of my html as the form is too long to show and same with all the header.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function email() {

    var emailUrl = "../assets/php/email_form_processing.php";

    $.ajax({
      url: emailUrl,
      method: 'post',
      data: $('#email_form').serialize(),
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        if (result) {
          alert("Email sent successfully");
        } else {
          alert("Failed!");
        }

      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<form id="email_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="button" id="email_submit" name="sendmail" class="btn btn-info" value="Send" onclick="email()">
</form>
```

Comment: You defined `email()` within the jQuery document.ready handler, hence it's not available to the `onclick` attribute, as they run in a higher scope. To fix this place the `email()` function definition outside document.ready. *Or, better yet*, don't use outdated `on*` event attributes at all. Attach the event handler using jQuery's `on()` or `click()` in this case.

Comment: Also, on closer inspection of your logic, it appears you're attempting to run this code when the form is submit. In this case don't use the click event of the button, but instead the `submit` event of the form. Make sure to call `preventDefault()` on the passed event too, otherwise the form will still be submit in the standard (ie. non-AJAX) way

Comment: thanks everyone, works now

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of `$(document).ready(function() {` (as it makes the function unavailable outside the ready function)

Your function should be simply as below

```
function email(){
 // your code here
}
```

Additionally, if you are using jQuery, try like following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#email_submit").click(function(event){
         // your code here
   });
```

});